# How can I populate properties of array item in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, populate

I have 3 collections `scopes`, `groups` and `users`

```
const ScopesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    privilege: String,
  }
);
```

```
const GroupsSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    status: String,
  }
);
```

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        security:[{
            _id:false,
            group: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "groups" },
            scopes: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "scopes" }],
        }], 
    },
);
```

Is possible to populate data from properties `group` and `scopes` in a document like this?

```
{
   _id: 44ffbvb...,
   security: [{
     "group": "44ffbvb...", // ID of document in groups collection
     "scopes": ["44ffbvb...","44ffbvb..."] // IDs of documents in scopes collection
   }]
}
```

I'd like to get the information related to group and scopes in order to get a document like this:

```
{
   _id: 44ffbvb...,
   security: [{
     "group": {
        "id" : "44ffbvb...",
        "name" : "Name of the group",
        "status": "ACTIVE"
     },
     "scopes": [{name: "ADMINISTRATOR", privilege: "write-only" },{name: "ROOT", privilege: "read-only" }]  
   }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the npm package
[mongoose-autopopulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate)

The fields you need to be populated, add : autopopulate: true,
and add this line to the schema-
schema.plugin(require('mongoose-autopopulate'));